# Problems doing animation with multiple plots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, animation, subplot

I'm trying to do an animation of 4 lines in 4 different subplots using matplotlib. But I only get the entire plot for a brief moment, and then the plots are empty.
The code format I'm using is similar to other examples I have made, without any issue. So I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any idea? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

%matplotlib nbagg

df = pd.read_csv (r"C:\Users\Gaizka\Downloads\V296_220719_38.csv")
t = df.iloc[:,0]
vert = df.iloc[:, 1]
long = df.iloc[:, 2]
tras = df.iloc[:, 3]
sound = df.iloc[:, 4]

x1, y1= [],[]
x2, y2= [],[]
x3, y3= [],[]
x4, y4= [],[]
tdata1, tdata2, tdata3, tdata4 = [], [],[],[]



fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(4,1,1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(4,1,2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(4,1,3)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(4,1,4)


ax1.grid(True)
ax1.set_ylabel('Vertical Velocity [mm/s]')
ax1.set_xlim (0,8200)
l1, = ax1.plot ([],[],'b-')

ax2.grid(True)
ax2.set_ylabel('Longitudinal Velocity [mm/s]')
ax2.set_xlim (0,8200)
l2, = ax1.plot ([],[],'g-')

ax3.grid(True)
ax3.set_ylabel('Trasversal Velocity [mm/s]')
ax3.set_xlim (0,8200)
l3, = ax1.plot ([],[],'r-')

ax4.grid(True)
ax4.set_xlabel('Time [ms]')
ax4.set_ylabel('Sound [dBl]')
ax4.set_xlim (0,8200)
l4, = ax1.plot ([],[],'k-')

l1, = ax1.plot (t, vert, 'b-')
l2, = ax2.plot (t, long, 'g-')
l3, = ax3.plot (t, tras, 'r-')
l4, = ax4.plot (t, sound, 'k-')


def init():    
    l1.set_data([],[])
    l2.set_data([],[])
    l3.set_data([],[])
    l4.set_data([],[])  
    return fig, 

def animate(i,l1,l2,l3,l4):

    x1.append (tdata1[i])
    y1.append (vert[i])
    x2.append (tdata2[i])
    y2.append (long[i])
    x3.append (tdata3[i])
    y3.append (tras[i])
    x4.append (tdata4[i])
    y4.append (sound[i])

    l1.set_data(tdata1,vert)
    l2.set_data(tdata2,long)
    l3.set_data(tdata3,tras)
    l4.set_data(tdata4,sound)  

    return fig,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, fargs=(l1,l2,l3,l4), frames=len (t), init_func=init, interval=10, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: In the call to FuncAnimation you have set interval to 10, which I think means only 10 milliseconds. Is that correct, or is it too short?

Comment: The interval is short because the file has a great deal of data to plot. And I have tried longer intervals, but the output is always the same. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `init()` and `animate()` functions must return a list of *artists*, not a reference to the figure.

you should have:

```
def init():
    (...)
    return (l1,l2,l3,l4)

def animate(i, l1, l2, l3, l4):
    (...)
    return (l1,l2,l3,l4)
```

**EDIT** Although my suggestion above still stands, that was not actually the problem.

In your `animate()` function, you refer to an array `tdata1[i]` but `tdata1` is initialized as an empty list and after that never used. Therefore the function raises an `IndexError`. In addition, I did not understand why you are copying the content of your dataframe in separate x1,y1,...,x4,y4 lists. Try this instead:

```
def animate(i,l1,l2,l3,l4):
    l1.set_data(t[:i],vert[:i])
    l2.set_data(t[:i],long[:i])
    l3.set_data(t[:i],tras[:i])
    l4.set_data(t[:i],sound[:i])
    return (l1,l2,l3,l4)
```

In general, to debug animations, I find it useful to call `animate()` by hand. Instead of creating the `FuncAnimation`, call `animate(10, l1, l2, l3, l4)` and see if the code raises an exception or if it produces the expected plot.

Comment: Thanks, Diziet Asahi !! But it didn`t work. The same result: The entire plot appears briefly and sudenly everything except the axes dissapears,...

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was to quick to assume the origin of the problem. I think I've seen the bug, please see my edit above